# Using array to store variables from file and copy to home directory from different user

Tags: shell

> I have one file with multiple filenames in it (with their absolute path). I need to copy those file in my home directory from the server & the owner of the files are different. I can use "dzdo su - username" to switch to user. How I can achieve the same ?????

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to just copy the files in the way you already are then and then run `chown -R' on them to change ownership:

```
cp -r /path/to/specialdirectory /home/someuser/

chown someuser -R /home/someuser/specialdirectory
```

Or I suppose you could also `chown` them one at a time to the correct user as you copy them in.